# RewriteRule: bad flag delimiter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

When I try to run the localhost with an .htaccess of the above, I get a HTTP Error 500 with the localhost page not loading.

The Apache error log says:

```
[Thu Dec 15 13:17:18 2016] [alert] [client ::1] /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/shopping cart/cart/public/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

Comment: [this seems to suggest there is probably a newline or unprintable character messing it up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27323274/htaccess-rewriterule-bad-flag-delimiters).  have you taken steps to rewrite the file to be sure that is not the case?

Comment: I believe that I have. I've also checked out the syntax on the htaccesscheck website to see if I was bugging but it reported that my syntax is okay.

Comment: have you tried removing `[QSA,L]` entirely?  it may not do what you want, but it will be a next troubleshooting step.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too, and it didn't change anything.

Comment: that is not logical  the *only* delimiters you have are those.  or are they? do you have other lines in your file?

Comment: No I don't, that's the only lines in the file. I'll try redoing the folder. Maybe something else is glitching it.